# why don't my pointers work?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to write the old painter game, where you paint around squares and when the perimeter is done the square changes colour, using ncurses.  I have written a simple level editor that lets me draw the squares using an asterisk.  I have a block structure and an array of them and can create the blocks by brute-force scanning the screen for asterisks and setting blocks to those locations.  So I realised that each block is joined to 2 - 4 other blocks, so I could just have pointers to next up/dn/lt/rt blocks and follow the pointers.  This would save time because I wouldn't have to check for boundary conditions or that the player stayed on the line, i could simply check if the ptr was null and if so not let the player move in that direction.  So I can save the block array and load it into the painter game and it displays it all correctly.  I have a ptr to the current block cur_blk which I have set to point to array element 5, and this works.  If I gdb, I can print out the value of *cur_blk and it shows everthing is right, but the pointers don't work.  I think the problem is in the level editor, but I am stuck.

Here is some code.  This is the block struct:

```
struct block{
int id;
int row, col;
int alive;

struct block *next_up, *next_dn, *next_lt, *next_rt;
struct square *my_squares;
```

};

Here is the block array setup:

```
struct block *bp;
int cnt = 0;

for(bp = &the_blocks[0]; bp < &the_blocks[1024]; bp++){
    bp->id = cnt;   
    bp->row = 0;
    bp->col = 0;
    bp->alive = FALSE;

    bp->next_up = NULL;
    bp->next_dn = NULL;
    bp->next_lt = NULL;
    bp->next_rt = NULL;

    bp->my_squares = (struct square *)malloc(sizeof(struct square)*4);
    cnt++;
}
```

here is the code to give the blocks the correct co-ords, and link them together - the linky code is in the `for(d=0;d<blk_cnt;d++)` loop.  It rescans the array comparing co-ords, such that if the row is one less and the col is the same then that is set to `the_blocks[c].next_up`.  I am pretty sure this is where the error is but I don't know what it is.

```
char cc, dn_ch, rt_ch; // cur/next chars
    int row, col;

    //create blocks

    for(row=0;row<24;row++){
        for(col=0;col<61;col++){
            cc = mvinch(row,col);

            if(cc == '*'){
                the_blocks[blk_cnt].row = row;
                the_blocks[blk_cnt].col = col;
                the_blocks[blk_cnt].alive = TRUE;
                blk_cnt++;
            }

            if(row<24) ;
                dn_ch = mvinch(row+1, col);

            if(col<60) ;
                rt_ch = mvinch(row,col+1);

            if(cc == '*' && dn_ch == '*' && rt_ch == '*')
                make_square(row,col);
        }
    }

    //make into squares and link blocks

    int c,d,e, scnt;

    for(c=0;c<blk_cnt;c++){
        int row = the_blocks[c].row;
        int col = the_blocks[c].col;

        for(e=0;e<sq_cnt;e++){
            // for each square, check top/base then left side and rigth side.
            // use tlx, tly etc
            scnt = 0;

            int tlx = the_squares[e].tlx;
            int tly = the_squares[e].tly;
            int blx = the_squares[e].blx;
            int bly = the_squares[e].bly;
            int trx = the_squares[e].trx;
            int try = the_squares[e].try;
            int brx = the_squares[e].brx;
            int bry = the_squares[e].bry;

            if(row == tly && col >=tlx && col <= trx){
                the_blocks[c].my_squares[scnt] = the_squares[e];
                scnt++;
            }
            if(row == bly && col >=blx && col <= brx){
                the_blocks[c].my_squares[scnt] = the_squares[e];
                scnt++;
            }
            if(col == tlx && row >=tly && row <= bly){
                the_blocks[c].my_squares[scnt] = the_squares[e];
                scnt++;
            }
            if(col == trx && row >=try && row <= bry){
                the_blocks[c].my_squares[scnt] = the_squares[e];
                scnt++;
            }
        }

        for(d=0;d<blk_cnt;d++){
            if((the_blocks[d].row == row-1) && (the_blocks[d].col == col)){
                //the_blocks[c].next_up = (struct block *)malloc(sizeof(struct block));
                the_blocks[c].next_up = &the_blocks[d];
            }
            if((the_blocks[d].row == row+1) && (the_blocks[d].col == col)){
                //the_blocks[c].next_dn = (struct block *)malloc(sizeof(struct block));
                the_blocks[c].next_dn = &the_blocks[d];
            }
            if(( the_blocks[d].col == col-1) && (the_blocks[d].row == row)){
                //the_blocks[c].next_lt = (struct block   )malloc(sizeof(struct block));
                the_blocks[c].next_lt = &the_blocks[d];
            }
            if((the_blocks[d].col == col+1) && (the_blocks[d].row == row)){
                //the_blocks[c].next_rt = (struct block *)malloc(sizeof(struct block));
                the_blocks[c].next_rt = &the_blocks[d];
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code from the painter game that sets the cur_blk pointer

```
cur_blk = &the_blocks[5];
move(cur_blk->row, cur_blk->col);
addch('@');
refresh();
```

and this is the move code, where I thought I could just follow the pointers:

```
switch(dir){
    case UP    : if(cur_blk->next_up != NULL){
                    cur_blk = cur_blk->next_up;
                    moved = TRUE;
                    break;
    }
    case DOWN  : if(cur_blk->next_dn != NULL){
                    cur_blk = cur_blk->next_dn;
                    moved = TRUE;
                    break;
    }
    case LEFT  : if(cur_blk->next_lt != NULL){
                    cur_blk = cur_blk->next_lt;
                    moved = TRUE;
                    break;
    }
    case RIGHT : if(cur_blk->next_rt != NULL){
                    cur_blk = cur_blk->next_rt;
                    moved = TRUE;
                    break;
    }
}
```

I am so stuck it is unreal. Thanks in advance for any help.  I can post more code if needed.  The level editor works apart from the linky bit!

Comment: They work, just not the way you expect them to work.

Comment: @VladLazarenko Not a very helpful comment. Did you spot an error? To the OP, can you reduce the code to an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) by stripping out anything not absolutely necessary to demonstrate the problem (or the behavior that you don't understand)? The code as posted here is probably too long for most SO users to read fully.

Comment: It is unclear what the "move" function expects as arguments - are you passing the integers and expecting to be able to modify the pointers? (or did you just plug in that code without using a function at all?)

Comment: Read this: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and then get yourself a rubber duck.

Comment: @NiRR move()is part of ncurses and takes two integers, row and col, which it gets from the pointer, vis: `cur_blk->row` and `cur_blk->col`

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys. @NiRR - I tried making a SSCCE and got it to print the values to screen and whadyaknow, the pointers are fine, it is an i/o error!